# If MIT licensed code links to GPL licensed code what should be the license of the resulting binary program?

Tags: gpl, mit

Scenario:

I have written a program that uses a GPLv2 library. The source code to *my program* is publicly available under an MIT license. For the sake of this example let's say my program links to the GPL library statically.

I would like to make the program available to download in binary form.

What license can / should the resulting binary program be covered by? Can I license my program to end users under the MIT license, or must it be GPL?

Comment: Rather than asking legal questions to random strangers on the Internet I suggest you should obtain an opinion on this topic from an attorney who is well-versed in copyright law, and follow his advice. Full disclosure: I am not a lawyer..

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica How do we know an expert in copyright law won't answer the question? In any case, I'm not asking for formal legal advice, I'm looking for *opinions* in a forum where people who may have some experience in this area. If someone wants legal advice, of course it's best to contact a lawyer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are free to distribute *your* source code under the MIT license. But the software in its entirety is derived from GPLv2-covered software, and therefore must be made available under the GPLv2 as well. In particular, your binaries directly *contain* GPLv2-covered software.

Because you are not the full copyright holder of this software but only a licensee of the GPLv2-covered components, you have no other choice (except not distributing binaries at all).

It is also possible to make an argument that your source code would be bound by the GPLv2, but that is not currently the mainstream interpretation.

Answer (score -2):

By law you have the sole rights to any of your own creative works. This include code written by you.

No-one has any right to demand you to license your work under any license they want. Instead, you have the freedom to choose any license for your work yourself.

If you combine your code with code licensed under the GPLv2 then you are obligated to release **only** the source code of **said code** but **not yours**. Licensing the end product is tricky because you only hold the copyright to your own code but at the same time no one can force you the terms of your license for your code. So basically **you have to explain this to the end-user that there are two separate codes with different licenses (one with the GPLv2 and other with MIT) and not one code with either license**. This myth like Gnu licenses somehow "infect" code is outright lie. The law protects you and your rights. Even if you have contributed to any project under the Gnu license you still have the right to demand that your contributions would be removed from the project if one day you choose so. Because only you have the copyright to your code and no license can ever take that away from you. This is actually the biggest legal problem (but not the only one) of restrictive copyleft licenses. Because with permissive open source licenses both the contributor and the "project manager"/"Copyright holder of the initial code" have the same rights (but no obligations) therefore there would be no reason for anyone ever to withdraw their code.

Many people fail to understand that there is no contract or license that can take away your right given by law. The same way for example, if child labour and slavery are banned by law then even if someone manages to contract a minor or sells themself into bondage than such contracts are legally void. Not only that but the other side to sign such contracts gets punished by the law.

Comment: This seems more like a rant than an answer, and it's a pretty odd point of view as well.  You really need to support some of the assertions you're making.

Comment: @MadHatter What assertions? I'm talking about the law. You want me to cite the copyright law or the labour law? What seems to be like a rant to you?

Comment: "*If you combine your code with code licensed under the GPLv2 then you are obligated to release only the source code of said code but not yours*" this contradicts GPLv2 s2b, for example.  And if you're going to start talking about "*the law*", you need to make reference to jurisdiction, because copyright law varies between them; failure to be clear about which jurisdiction you have in mind doesn't help the appearance of your answer.

Comment: You are right. After article 13 things in EU got bit more confusing. I was originally talking about U.S. Digital Millennium Copyright Act but for the most part copyright works roughly the same way in most western civilised world. In any case, GPLv2 s2b talks about "derivative work" meaning you have edited already existing code - not added your own code in different file. The whole 2 clause is talking about "modifying" and actually it's good that you point out that when not modified, according to that clause - it doesn't even have to be redistributed in source form.

Comment: You are right that GPLv2 s2b does not require source redistribution when redistributing unmodified; s3a, however, **does** require that.  s2b makes it clear that the derivative work is *the work as a whole*, not just the individual source file.  It's good that you're thinking about the GPL in a detailed way, but I would **strongly** advise against considering a work to be arbitrarily divisible into unrelated subworks for copyright purposes.  Courts have ruled on the GPL already, and none has supported *that* viewpoint.

Comment: It is derivative work **only** if the GPL source has been modified. Please read again s3a It references back to s2 which means they are talking about modifications and **not** separate, but linked code. Courts have ruled for outright license violations, not where the line goes between derivative or separate works.

Comment: Not only are you conflating the two separate points I make in my last comment, but when you say "*Courts have [not] ruled ... where the line goes between derivative or separate works*" this is simply wrong; consider eg [Drauglis v. Kappa Map Group](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Drauglis_v._Kappa_Map_Group,_LLC), which turns on precisely that question.

Comment: @MadHatter Do you even read the text you are linking to? "...Because the atlas was published "**in its entirety in unmodified form**"..."

It says it right there that it was in **unmodified form**. In Europe that wouldn't have even classified as "collective work" since there was no changes - but with changes it would have been derivative work and thank you again to confirm what I said earlier. 

Besides, I thought we were talking about **software licenses** and the **legal problems open source community have** faced for decades now, **not about photographs**?

Comment: You're conflating two points again.  Leave aside for a moment the question of modified vs. unmodified.  You said that courts have not ruled on the distinction  between derivative and separate works.  I'm just letting you know that they have, in the context of free licences, and pointed you to a concrete example.  Incidentally, copyright law is not different in most jurisdictions for software compared to other forms of content, so it might be best to be less snippy about the exact material that is *sub judice*.

Comment: "You said that courts have not ruled on the distinction between derivative and separate works." That's exactly what I said - **in the context of open source code**. The context matters. I'm talking about one thing and you keep steering away from it. Also your case was pure license violation, that you are trying to confuse with the modification question.

Comment: **There is no copyright difference between copylefted code and copylefted content**.

Comment: @Smart455 The reason Linus has a kernel syscall exception in his license for linux is because a straightforward reading of the GPL says that if you use GPL licensed code in your project and compile them together, you've created a derivative work and it must be licensed under the GPL. There is no U.S. law which says otherwise, though I don't know much about the relevant court decisions.

Comment: @Smart455: two questions arise: 1) are you an attorney? and 2) are you well-versed in copyright law? If the answer to either is "No" then I suggest that OP should consult such an attorney to get a reliable opinion.